# SSRS Dataset Query Parameter From Custom Code Returning Array of String

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

**Problem**
Using a parameter in a dataset query which would sometimes be just a string and other times multiple values where the values are being returned from custom code.

**Example Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE tblCol IN (@Parameter)
```

Sometimes all that would be returned in @Parameter would be a simple string value and other times it would need to be multiple string values.

Answer (score 0):

To handle for this:

1. Create the query in the Dataset Properties window and specify the name for your parameter
2. Select the Parameters option in Dataset Properties
3. You'll see the parameter you created in your query listed. Click on the function button
4. Associate the parameter with the proper function, i.e in the expression window something like =Code.myfunction()

Your function would then need to return, like so (notice no specification of what data type the function will return (ReturnType) which is important as if you specify "as string" or "as string()" or whatever it won't work correctly):

```
Function myfunction()
Return {"value1","value2"}
End Function
```

If your function is going to be dynamically returning different strings at different times, just make sure every return is wrapped with {}. This will handle returning one value or multiple.